# Benefits of OFBiz 10.04 over OFBiz 4.0

Tags: e-commerce, ofbiz

Can anyone tell what are the benefits I can get with using OFBiz 10.04 rather than OFBiz 4.0. In other words, I want to upgrade from OFBiz 4.0 to OFBiz 10.04. What benifits I will get?

Answer (score 1):

OFBiz 4.0 is no more supported by the communauty. 10.04 is a svn branch from april 2010 which is only receiving correction patchs.
This is a much more up-to-date version, you will find more info there :  https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/feature-summary.html